# Does exact sequence remain exact in opposite category?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

In an abelian category $C$, we have the following two exact sequences 
$$0\to P\to Q\to R$$
$$0\to P'\to Q'\to R'$$
We also have the maps
$$u:P\to P'$$
$$v:Q\to Q'$$
$$w:R\to R'$$

Here $u,v,w$ are such that the diagram with the exact rows and connected by these maps ($u,v,w$) commutes i.e. we have a morphism of the exact sequences.
Then we can show that the following sequence is exact:
$$0\to ker(u)\to ker(v)\to ker(w)$$
The exactness of the kernel sequence I have established. Now I want to know what would be the dual statement of this i.e. considering the corresponding sequence in opposite category can we say also that the cokernel sequence is exact (with zero on the right). The problem in showing this I am having is the following:

Does an exact sequence remains exact in opposite category.I think that's not going to hold. If this is not true then what would be the dual statement and how to establish it? (first I thought that the dual statement would be 
$$coker(w)\to coker(v)\to coker(u)\to0$$
is an exact sequence, but I am in deep suspicion about my first thought now)...Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, kernels in a category go to cokernels in the opposite category: $gf=0$ in the opposite category iff $fg=0$ in the original category, so the cokernel of $f$ is sent to the kernel of $f$. So exact sequences remain exact, but sequences exact on just one side become exact on the other side.