# Direct limit and inverse limit in relation to exact sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In Ab, it is clear that direct limit of something is coker of some map and inverse limit of something else is ker of some other map. Direct limit is preserved by left exact functor preserving arbitrary direct sums whereas inverse limit is preserved by right exact functor preserving arbitrary direct products. So I hope to guess that direct limit is a left exact functor and inverse limit is a right exact functor. This happens to be the case. I have two questions.

1. In general, given a left exact functor $L:Ab\to Ab$ and another functor $T$ for test, if $LT\not\cong TL$ natually, can I conclude that $T$ cannot be left exact? I think one can replace $Ab$ by some other category containing some zero object in the category to construct similar exact sequence. Does this sort of argument hold in general?
2. Direct limit is exact functor which is much stronger than inverse limit. What is the intuitive reason this strangeness happens to be the case even though direct limit is basically dualization of inverse limit? There seems some inequal distribution of properties in terms of dualization as an exact sequence looks the same if I just apply $(-)^{op}$ functor.

---

The exact sequence remains exact in $C^{op}$ category.([Does exact sequence remain exact in opposite category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463796/does-exact-sequence-remain-exact-in-opposite-category))

Answer (score 0):

For first question,consider Hom functor $Hom(B,-)$,it is right adjoint functor. So it preserves inverse limit.

- We know it does't preserve direct limit.if index set is directed,then direct limit is a exact functor. This is a counterexample.

Comment: We can also consider $Hom(-,B)$,this is left exact,we have $Hom(lim_{\rightarrow},B)\cong lim_{\leftarrow}Hom(-,B)$.when I is directed,direct limit is exact functor

Comment: Generically, I was thinking both T and L are of same variance. $Hom(A,-)$ commutes with inverse limit and tensor commutes with direct limit. Does the statement hold in this case?

Comment: $Hom(A,lim_{\rightarrow}-)\ncong lim_{\rightarrow}Hom(A,-)$

Comment: @user45765 but $lim_{\rightarrow}$is exact functor when index set is directed.